# Changing Text Value With JavaScript Doesn't Affect It's Real Value

Tags: javascript

I want to change text element with javascript code and click the button. I'm changing html text value with javascript code :

```
document.getElementsByName('query')[0].value = "test";
```

and i'm focusing in that element with :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('input choice-input text-input')[0].focus();
```

and then i'm clicking the button :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('choice-input load-button')[0].click();
```

But at the end the text element still has old variable in it. It's looks like working but it's just visually i guess. When i type some character after running

`document.getElementsByName('query')[0].value = "test";`

code and then delete it manually it's working. I think i should change text element with another code or i have to refresh it somehow. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: Could you add code samples here to show your dom structure?

Comment: @Viney I edited my question